# How do I combine the congruences $p=\pm 1\mod 8$ and $p=\pm 1\mod 5$

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

How do I combine the congruences $p=\pm 1\mod 8$ and $p=\pm 1\mod 5$ into a congruence $\mod 40$ where $p$ is an odd prime? I can see by writing out values the answer is $p=\pm 1\mod 40$ and $p=\pm 9\mod 40$

Comment: If you can see the answer where is the question?

Comment: How do I prove that this is the answer*?

Comment: As you said, by writing out the values.

Comment: Chinese remainder theorem proves there is one answer modulo $40$ for each pair of values.

Comment: I just used CRT. Is it okay to consider it as two equations and just use $\pm$ throughout? I got the right answer.

Comment: Perhaps you could include all your steps in the question. Otherwise people can't really say whether your method was OK, all they can do is show their own solutions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using Chinese Remainder Theorem, you can prove that since $\gcd(8, 5) = 1$, for each value $a \mod 8$ and $b \mod 5$, you will always have unique $c\mod 40$.

1) $p = 1 \mod 8, p = 1 \mod 5$ yields $p = 1 \mod 40$
2) $p = 7 \mod 8, p = 1 \mod 5$ yields $p = 31 \mod 40$
3) $p = 1 \mod 8, p = 4 \mod 5$ yields $p = 9 \mod 40$
4) $p = 7 \mod 8, p = 4 \mod 5$ yields $p = 39 \mod 40$

Answer (score 1):

**1. case**

If $p=5a+1$ and $p=8b-1$ then $5a+1=8b-1$ so $$5\mid 8b-2\implies 5\mid 16b-4\implies 5\mid b+1$$

so $b+1=5c$ and thus $$p= 8(5c-1)-1 = 40c-9$$
i.e. $$ p\equiv-9 \pmod{40}$$

Similary you do the other cases...